# How to read a table from an Excel document that has empty rows using Laravel

Tags: php, excel, laravel, laravel-5

Hello guys i have a problem reading a table from an Excel document that doesnt start from raw 1 colone 1 (A1) using LARAVEL, in this docuement there is a title and some empty rows, as the image show : [Excel table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qk8v5.png).)

here is the code that i have used to load a table from the document, meanwhile it works fine if i deleted all the title text and all the empty cells !

```
     Excel::load(Input::file('file'), function($reader) {

// Getting all results
$results = $reader->get();
foreach ($results as $r =>$v) {
     $person = new Person;
        $person->name = $v['name'];
        $person->age = $v['age'];
        $person->save();
}
```

Comment: What extension or tool do you use to read excel files?

Comment: i'm using maatwebsite/excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yupiiii!! found a solution for this issue, by going to the config file : 
***\laravel-Project\config\excel.php***
and change the following line:

```
  /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | First Row with data or heading of data
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If the heading row is not the first row, or the data doesn't start
    | on the first row, here you can change the start row.
    |
    */

    'startRow'                => 1,
```

and change the number 1 by whatever row your table start ^^ !